# Jasmine testing controller from wrong ui-router state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, jasmine

I have a page where everything works fine.  However, my test for this page's controller `FeeRuleCtrl`, after it tests the code of said controller, goes on and starts testing the controller of a different state.  Here's my app.js:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('root', {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: "<%= Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.client_side_path('admin/fee_suites/root') %>",
    controller: 'RootCtrl',
    resolve: {
      feeSuites: function(FeeSuiteCrud, FeeSuite){
        console.log('here');
        var feeCrud = new FeeSuiteCrud(FeeSuite);
        var promise = feeCrud.query();

        return promise.then(function(response){
          return response;
        });
      }
    }
  })
  .state('fee-rule', {
    abstract: true,
    controller: 'FeeRuleCtrl',
    template: "<ui-view/>",
    resolve: {
      feeTypes: function(FeeSuiteCrud, FeeType){
        var feeCrud = new FeeSuiteCrud(FeeType)
        var promise = feeCrud.query();

        return promise.then(function(response){
          return response;
        })
      },
      feeSuites: function(FeeSuiteCrud, FeeSuite){
        var feeCrud = new FeeSuiteCrud(FeeSuite);
        var promise = feeCrud.query();

        return promise.then(function(response){
          return response;
        });
      }
    }
  })
  .state('fee-rule.new', {
    url: '/new',
    controller: 'NewCtrl',
    templateUrl: "<%= Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.client_side_path('admin/fee_suites/feeRule.html') %>",
    data: { title: 'Add a New Fee Rule' }
  })
  .state('fee-rule.edit', {
    url: "/edit/:id",
    controller: 'EditCtrl',
    templateUrl: "<%= Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.client_side_path('admin/fee_suites/feeRule.html') %>",
    data: { title: 'Edit Fee Rule' },
    resolve: {
      feeRule: function(FeeSuiteCrud, FeeRule, $stateParams){
        var feeCrud = new FeeSuiteCrud(FeeRule);
        var promise = feeCrud.get($stateParams.id)

        return promise.then(function(response){
          return response;
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

I have an abstract state, `fee-rule`, because both the `new` and `edit` states share most of the same functionality.

When I go to the page's address, `<host>/admin/fee_suites/new`, I inspect the network tab and there are 4 server calls made:

```
api/v3/fee_types
api/v3/fee_suites
api/v3/fee_suites/8?association=fee_rules
api/v3/fee_types/9?association=fee_parameters
```

The first 2 are resolves in the `fee-rule` state.  I take care of this like so in the test:

```
beforeEach(function(){
  module(function($provide){
    $provide.factory('feeSuites', function(FeeSuite){
      feeSuite = new FeeSuite({
        id: 8,
        site_id: 9,
        active: true
      });

      return [feeSuite];
    });

    $provide.factory('feeTypes', function(FeeType){
      feeType = new FeeType({
        id: 9,
        name: 'Carrier Quotes',
        value: 'carrier_quotes'
      });

      return [feeType];
    });
  });

  inject(function($injector){
    $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
    $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    $controller("FeeRuleCtrl", {
      '$scope': scope
    });
  });
});
```

The last 2 server calls are made inside `FeeRuleCtrl`.  I test them like so:

```
beforeEach(function(){
  var JSONResponse = {"master":[{"id":29,"fee_suite_id":8,"fee_parameter_id":1,"name":"American Express Fee","multiplier":0.045,"addend":0.0,"order":1,"order_readonly":true,"created_at":"2016-10-17T14:20:08.000-05:00","updated_at":"2016-10-17T14:20:08.000-05:00"},{"id":30,"fee_suite_id":8,"fee_parameter_id":2,"name":"Discover Fee","multiplier":0.045,"addend":0.0,"order":1,"order_readonly":true,"created_at":"2016-10-17T14:20:08.000-05:00","updated_at":"2016-10-17T14:20:08.000-05:00"},{"id":31,"fee_suite_id":8,"fee_parameter_id":3,"name":"MasterCard Fee","multiplier":0.045,"addend":0.0,"order":1,"order_readonly":true,"created_at":"2016-10-17T14:20:08.000-05:00","updated_at":"2016-10-17T14:20:08.000-05:00"},{"id":32,"fee_suite_id":8,"fee_parameter_id":4,"name":"Visa Fee","multiplier":0.045,"addend":0.0,"order":1,"order_readonly":true,"created_at":"2016-10-17T14:20:08.000-05:00","updated_at":"2016-10-17T14:20:08.000-05:00"}]};

  $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/v3/fee_suites/8?association=fee_rules').respond(JSONResponse);

  JSONResponse = {"master":[{"id":25,"fee_type_id":9,"name":"UPS Published Quote","value":"ups_published_quote","parameter_type":"currency","created_at":"2016-10-17T14:20:08.000-05:00","updated_at":"2016-10-17T14:20:08.000-05:00"},{"id":26,"fee_type_id":9,"name":"FedEx Published Quote","value":"fedex_published_quote","parameter_type":"currency","created_at":"2016-10-17T14:20:08.000-05:00","updated_at":"2016-10-17T14:20:08.000-05:00"},{"id":27,"fee_type_id":9,"name":"UPS Negotiated Quote","value":"ups_negotiated_quote","parameter_type":"currency","created_at":"2016-10-17T14:20:08.000-05:00","updated_at":"2016-10-17T14:20:08.000-05:00"},{"id":28,"fee_type_id":9,"name":"FedEx Negotiated Quote","value":"fedex_negotiated_quote","parameter_type":"currency","created_at":"2016-10-17T14:20:08.000-05:00","updated_at":"2016-10-17T14:20:08.000-05:00"}]};

  $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/v3/fee_types/9?association=fee_parameters').respond(JSONResponse);

  $httpBackend.flush();
});

it('should set currentFeeRuleNum', function(){
  expect(scope.FeeSuite.currentFeeRuleNum).toEqual(4);
});
```

When I run my test I get the following error:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET /api/v3/fee_suites/
```

I know it is coming from `root` state's resolve function `feeSuites` because the test also prints to the console log the word 'here'.

I cannot figure out why it seems like the test doesn't stop and starts testing the `RootCtrl` in the `root` state.  Could it have anything to do with the fact that state `fee-rule` is abstract?  Also `NewCtrl` is defined but it is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more googling with different keywords, turns out in my test I need to mock the $state variable inside FeeRuleCtrl.  That fixed the problem.